# Regular expression to validate last digits

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

How can I validate the last digits of URL `/?d=123`

the URL will always ends with /?d=(no more than 4 numbers) ex.12345 will never appear

```
http://www.test.com/?d=123
```

This is what i have, but I don't know how to match just the ones that end with `123` and `4321`

```
(http(s)?://)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?
```

Comment: What is your requirement? You want to ensure that only digits are present in the query parameter?

Comment: `/^\d+$/.test( url.split('=').pop() )`

Comment: if the only thing you're looking for in the url are digits you can use `/(\d+)/g` to get the numbers back. But this is a very loose regex.

Comment: @degant im trying to validate a url that ends(match) with 123 it has to be a valid url

Comment: @Pedro so the end of the URL has to be only 123 and nothing else?

Comment: Edit your question so it includes the requirement that you want to match a valid url, or you'll keep getting answers that just match numbers. Also - Is the parameter always named `d`?  Is it the only parameter?  Can it be `?d=123` or `&d=123` (if there's more than one parameter)? Do you want to match the _literal_ `123` or is it _any number_? These are things that have to be considered to come to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex to validate a URL for which the query parameter contains only digits (1 to 4 like OP suggested):

```
^(http(s)?://)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+([\w- ;,./%&=]*)\?((\w)+=(\d){1,4})$
```

Regex to validate a URL for which query parameters are either 123 or 4321:

```
^(http(s)?://)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+([\w- ;,./%&=]*)\?((\w)+=(123|4321))$
```

[Regexstorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28http%28s%29%3F%3A%2F%2F%29%28%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B.%29%2B%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B%28%5B%5Cw-%20%3B%2C.%2F%25%26%3D%5D*%29%5C%3F%28%28%5Cw%29%2B%3D%28123%7C4321%29%29%24&i=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fd%3D123)

EDIT: Minor modifications as per OP's requirements and @Stephen P's suggestions

Comment: OP: `?d=(no more than 4 numbers) ex.12345 will never appear` so `{1,4}`

Comment: Valid point @StephenP, thanks! Updated regex to allow only `{1,4}`

Comment: Thank you for you help, a quick question..i wast looking at your refiddle demo, and if we add 4321111, it highlights the link but ignores the last digits that don't match, to ignore the one that don't match

Comment: @Pedro that won't be a problem. You can simply add a dollar ($) at the end of the regex pattern to make sure this issue doesn't come in your code. Updated the answer with the same.

Comment: @degran I know that I already marked your asnwers as correct(and it is) I running your 'Regextorm' example and if I add the other link to the test area, dont highlight any link? do you know the reason ?

Comment: @Pedro `^` and `$` indicate start and end of string so we surrounded your pattern within these. However if you use these characters on refiddle or regexstorm then you *cannot* use the text box as a multi-line input for comparing multiple strings. So I remove those signs while testing multiple inputs. Hope this helps clarify your doubt!

Answer (score 1):

This is for matching only these values at the end:

```
/(123|4321)$/
```